# How to send Multiline sms using gnokii with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gnokii

dear all im tried to send multiline sms using gnikii but it fails

```
 Dim xCmd As String
    xCmd = "cmd.exe /c echo " & txtBody.Text & " | c:\sms\gnokii.exe --sendsms 0771234567 2> test.txt"
    Shell(xCmd)
```

Please help me

Comment: Fails with what response?

Comment: @damienc88 i cannot get response if im remove txtBody.text and put "hi" itwill recive to me

Answer (score 0):

You can split your text on vbCrLf and add echo in front so you end up with this cmdline instead

cmd.exe /c lineOne echo line2 | c:\sms\gnokii.exe --sendsms 0771234567 2> test.txt

code wise you can do it like this:

```
    Dim sString As String 
    Dim aLines As String()
    Dim xCmd As String

    sString = "lineOne" & vbCrLf & "line2"
    aLines = sString.Split(vbCrLf)
    sString = Join(aLines," echo")

    xCmd = "cmd.exe /c " & sString & " | c:\sms\gnokii.exe --sendsms 0771234567 2> test.txt"
    Shell(xCmd)
```